# Safari layout different than firefox

Tags: html, css

I have just checked out what my site would look like in safari and there is a padding difference on my table!

Where there is a table with one column that has text and another that has a form there is padding so that the text in the left column is not right up to the form! This is not the case in safari and im not sure why!

I would like the padding back please safari! lol
http://www.perfectclaims.com/ppiclaimsnew/index.php

I have took a picture of what it looks like in safari to show you what I mean! http://www.perfectclaims.com/ppiclaimsnew/safari.gif
You can see that the text is right up again the blue form!

Comment: why did i get voted down? I really dont understand why the padding is different!

Comment: you need to ask specific questions.  possibly even post some code that illustrates the problem.

Comment: Looks identical on my machine. Checked on IE8, FF3.5.2, SafariWin 4.0.3.

Comment: Looks OK on Chrome 3 on Windows XP. Which version of Safari are you talking about, and is it on Mac or Windows?

Comment: im using 4.0.2 on windows xp and my boss is using 3.2.3 on a mac!

Answer (score 1):

On second look, the textbox width is different in Safari. You may want to check that (with a ruler, perhaps? :D).

Otherwise, layout looks OK, unless you're aiming for pixel-perfect placement. Which is just absurd in this era of browser ubiquity.

**Update**:

Digging through the HTML, I took this snippet of HTML from one of your textboxes:

```
<input 
    name="fullname" 
    tabIndex="1" 
    class="formText" 
    id="fullname" 
    style="border-bottom: medium none; border-left: medium none; font-size: 20px; border-top: medium none; border-right: medium none;" 
    type="text" 
    size="30"
/>
```

Preferable, you may want to set the textbox size from the style attribute instead of size. That will give you more pixel perfect page.